# URL Rewrite issue to redirect

Tags: iis

I'm configuring a reverse proxy rule in my IIS, I want to redirect all traffic that arrive to my server on port 5050 to another server on port 8080 with regular expression, if I use (.*) the redirect works well, but if  try to change it to for example *5050* the redirect does not work even if I test the patter and none errors are showed.

See my rule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCwTC.png)

Tested rule

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c91pg.png)

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

In your Match URL, you use wildcards for matching, and  the asterisk ("*") means "match any number of any characters and capture them in a back-reference" and "?" means match exactly one character **(no back-reference is created)**, so {R:1} is invalid in Rewrite URL. I suggest you still use regular expressions to match.

More information about wildcards you can refer to this link: [Rule pattern syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-pattern-syntax).